# load fields from second recordType and append to main array

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have two recordTypes in a CloudKit container. One contains details for Gift Certificates, and the other is the packages they are sold for.

Table 2 is the child.

Table 1 (giftcert):

- id (int)
- giftto (string)
- giftfrom (string)
- package (reference)

Table 2 (package):

- pack_id (int)
- pack_name (string)
- pack_amount (int)

I have the below code so far - If this was an SQL statement, it would look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM giftcert LEFT JOIN package ON package = pack_id WHERE 1 SORT BY id ASC
```

I would like to have all of the records from "giftcert" displaying in the TableView (this I already have working). From there, I would like to be able to display the appropriate pack_name on the same cell.

So in the cell, you will have:

- Label 1 = giftcert.id
- Label 2 = giftcert.giftto
- Label 3 = package.pack_name

**giftcert.swift**

```
struct giftcert {

    let record: CKRecord!
    let id: Int
    let giftto: String
    let giftfrom: String
    let status: Int
    let expire: Date

    init(id: Int, giftto: String, giftfrom: String, status: Int, expire: Date) {
        self.id = id
        self.giftto = giftto
        self.giftfrom = giftfrom
        self.status = status
        self.expire = expire
        record = CKRecord(recordType: "giftcert")
        record["id"] = id as CKRecordValue?
        record["giftto"] = giftto as CKRecordValue?
        record["giftfrom"] = giftfrom as CKRecordValue?
        record["status"] = status as CKRecordValue?
        record["expire"] = expire as CKRecordValue?
    }

    init(record : CKRecord) {
        self.record = record
        self.id = record["id"] as! Int
        self.giftto = record["giftto"] as! String
        self.giftfrom = record["giftfrom"] as! String
        self.status = record["status"] as! Int
        self.expire = record["expire"] as! Date

    }
}
```

**Model.swift**

```
func refreshPublicDB() {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "giftcert", predicate: predicate)
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)
        query.sortDescriptors = [sort]

        publicDB.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { results, error in
            if let error = error {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.delegate?.errorUpdating(error as NSError)
                }
            } else {
                self.items.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
                for record in results! {
                    let item = giftcert(record: record)
                    self.items.append(item)
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.delegate?.publicDBUpdated()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where's your "package"/table 2 code?

Comment: nothing I have been able to produce has come close to being useful, hence i haven't posted any of it here. :/

Comment: I am confused by what exactly you are trying to achieve. The "but I can't figure out how to get the details from table 2 inline with table 1" part is especially vague. Perhaps if you could include a more detailed explanation of your objective I can try to help you better.

Comment: Hey @BenjaminLowry - I have amended the details above. Does this make it any clearer?

Comment: So doesn't this mean that the table 2 items and table 1 items are on the same table?

Comment: No, two different tables. Trying to link Table 2 to Table 1 something like what you would do with an SQL query.

Comment: Well I haven't worked with SQL before so sorry but that doesn't help. I am not sure if you are aware of this, but in iOS, you can't have tables with real columns. If you want two different objects in table format to be right next to each other, they need to be in the same cells.

Comment: from what I have read so far, and again, could be misinterpreting, but in iOS i would need to call a query from Table 2 within the query from Table 1. Essentially getting the value from Table 1.package, and using this to set the predicate to filter Table 2. The issue for me is getting this to work when running a query in a query doesn't seem right.